# AngularJS - draggable and multiple connected sortables (jQuery UI + angular-common)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to extend [angular-common](https://github.com/michaeljcalkins/angular-common)'s excellent [dragdrop module](https://github.com/michaeljcalkins/angular-common/blob/master/modules/dragdrop/dragdrop.js) which can handle a draggable connected to a single sortable. *(Original SO thread behind angular-common's dragdrop module is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835619/drag-object-into-sortable-list-angularjs).)*

I managed to connect two sortables, and dropping a draggable to each of them, and rearranging within the sortables work fine (scope item arrays get updated as expected). In fact the UI part works fine, but I can't seem figure out how to update the item arrays in the Angular scope when I drag a list item from one sortable to another.

Factory:

```
.factory('DragDropHandler', [function() {
    return {
        dragObject: undefined,
        addObject: function(object, objects, to) {
            objects.splice(to, 0, object);
        },
        moveObject: function(objects, from, to) {
            objects.splice(to, 0, objects.splice(from, 1)[0]);
        }
    };
}])
```

Droppable (sortable) directive:

```
.directive('droppable', ['DragDropHandler', function(DragDropHandler) {
    return {
        scope: {
            droppable: '=',
            ngUpdate: '&',
            ngCreate: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.sortable({
              connectWith: ['.draggable','.sortable'],
            });
            element.disableSelection();
            var list = element.attr('id');
            element.on("sortdeactivate", function(event, ui) {

                var from = angular.element(ui.item).scope().$index;
                var to = element.children().index(ui.item);

                //console.log('from: ' + from + ', to: ' +to);

                if (to >= 0 ){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        if (from >= 0) {
                            DragDropHandler.moveObject(scope.droppable, from, to, list);
                            scope.ngUpdate({
                                from: from,
                                to: to,
                                list: list
                            });
                        } else {

                            scope.ngCreate({
                                object: DragDropHandler.dragObject,
                                to: to,
                                list: list
                            });

                            ui.item.remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            element.on("sortremove", function(event, ui) {
              //console.log(element);
              //console.log('a sort item is removed from a connected list and is dragged into another.');
            });
            element.on("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
              //console.log(element);
              //console.log('item from a connected sortable list has been dropped.');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller functions:

```
$scope.updateObjects = function(from, to, list) {
    var itemIds = _.pluck($scope.items[list], 'id');
    //console.log(itemIds);
};

$scope.createObject = function(object, to, list) {
    console.log(list);
    console.log($scope.items[list]);
    var newItem = angular.copy(object);
    newItem.id = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
    DragDropHandler.addObject(newItem, $scope.items[list], to);
};

$scope.deleteItem = function(itemId) {
    $scope.items = _.reject($scope.items, function(item) {
        return item.id == itemId; 
    });
};
```

And the view:

```
<h3>sortable</h3>
<ul
    droppable='items.list1'
    ng-update='updateObjects(from, to)'
    ng-create='createObject(object, to, list)'
    id="list1" class="sortable">
    <li
        class="ui-state-default"
        ng-repeat="item in items.list1 track by item.id">
        {{ $index }}: {{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}
        <button
            ng-click='deleteItem(item.id)'
            class='btn btn-xs pull-right btn-danger'>X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<h3>sortable</h3>
<ul
    droppable='items.list2'
    ng-update='updateObjects(from, to)'
    ng-create='createObject(object, to, list)'
    id="list2" class="sortable">
    <li
        class="ui-state-default"
        ng-repeat="item in items.list2 track by item.id">
        {{ $index }}: {{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}
        <button
            ng-click='deleteItem(item.id)'
            class='btn btn-xs pull-right btn-danger'>X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Working example on Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/m4ft1Kw2sUTyJy1Qzj0d?p=preview)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it. I created a [fork on GitHub](https://github.com/orszaczky/angular-common/tree/master/modules/dragdrop), and  **[PLUNKER UPDATED!](http://plnkr.co/edit/m4ft1Kw2sUTyJy1Qzj0d?p=preview)**

*Explanation: The key was to check if `ui.sender` was set for the dragged object by another sortable list. If it was set, the object was coming from another sortable, otherwise not.*

The extended droppable (sortable) directive:

```
.directive('droppable', ['DragDropHandler', function(DragDropHandler) {
    return {
        scope: {
            droppable: '=',
            ngMove: '&',
            ngCreate: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.sortable({
              connectWith: ['.draggable','.sortable'],
            });
            element.disableSelection();
            var list = element.attr('id');
            element.on("sortupdate", function(event, ui) {

                var from = angular.element(ui.item).scope().$index;
                var to = element.children().index(ui.item);

                if (to >= 0 ){
                  //item is moved to this list
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        if (from >= 0) {
                          //item is coming from a sortable

                          if (!ui.sender) {
                            //item is coming from this sortable
                              DragDropHandler.moveObject(scope.droppable, from, to);

                          } else {
                            //item is coming from another sortable
                            scope.ngMove({
                                from: from,
                                to: to,
                                fromList: ui.sender.attr('id'),
                                toList: list
                            });
                            ui.item.remove();
                          }
                        } else {
                          //item is coming from a draggable
                            scope.ngCreate({
                                object: DragDropHandler.dragObject,
                                to: to,
                                list: list
                            });

                            ui.item.remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

In the controller I added a moveObject function that is responsible for moving the object from the old array to the new one:

```
$scope.moveObject = function(from, to, fromList, toList) {
    var item = $scope.items[fromList][from];
    DragDropHandler.addObject(item, $scope.items[toList], to);
    $scope.items[fromList].splice(0, 1);
}
```

And the deleteItem function had to be updated to handle multiple arrays of the multiple sortables (just to keep the demo fully working):

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(itemId) {
  for (var list in $scope.items) {
    if ($scope.items.hasOwnProperty(list)) {
      $scope.items[list] = _.reject($scope.items[list], function(item) {
        return item.id == itemId; 
      });
    }
  }
};
```

And the view:

```
<h3>sortable</h3>
<ul
    droppable='items.list2'
    ng-move='moveObject(from, to, fromList, toList)'
    ng-create='createObject(object, to, list)'
    id="list2" class="sortable">
    <li
        class="ui-state-default"
        ng-repeat="item in items.list2 track by item.id">
        {{ $index }}: {{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}
        <button
            ng-click='deleteItem(item.id)'
            class='btn btn-xs pull-right btn-danger'>X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I removed ngUpdate, as far as I could tell, it didn't have any actual functionality.